# Route all traffic from eth1 to go through tun0 (ssh)

Tags: ssh, iptables, ssh-tunnel

My pc has two physical network cards, `eth0` to access the internet and `eth1` to work as dhcp server to make several wireless router can access the internet.

I have enabled the kernel ip forwarding and add some rules using iptable:

`net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`

Everything works fine.

Now, I want to tunnel all the traffic of `eth1` to pass through `tun0` (the third virtual network interface created using [SSH_VPN](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH_VPN))

Here is my ifconfig outputs:

```
eth0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:dd:56:bb  
        inet addr:10.1.0.212  Bcast:10.1.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
        inet6 addr: fe80::ba27:ebff:fedd:56bb/64 Scope:Link
        UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
        RX packets:25131918 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
        TX packets:2234134 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
        collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
        RX bytes:1527934819 (1.5 GB)  TX bytes:342049206 (342.0 MB)

eth1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0e:c6:b2:60:90  
        inet addr:192.168.50.1  Bcast:192.168.50.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
        inet6 addr: fe80::20e:c6ff:feb2:6090/64 Scope:Link
        UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
        RX packets:1919359 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:0
        TX packets:321412 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
        collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
        RX bytes:135557477 (135.5 MB)  TX bytes:338750947 (338.7 MB)

tun0    Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
        inet addr:10.11.0.212  P-t-P:10.11.0.226  Mask:255.255.255.255
        UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
        RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:3 overruns:0 frame:0
        TX packets:3 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
        collisions:0 txqueuelen:500 
        RX bytes:492 (492.0 B)  TX bytes:252 (252.0 B)
```

How can I do the forwarding? I have tried several ways but no lucky :(

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the default route.

Here is the solution:

```
1. bring up ssh tunnel interface (10.11.0.212)
2. replace the default route using tunnel interface (10.11.0.1 over 10.1.0.1)
3. add a route for the tunnel remote to passthrough eth0 gateway (e.g. x.x.x.x via 10.1.0.1)
4. ip forward for eth1
```